# надо чтоб сначала одно заданное множество выводилось, а потом другое. но все элементы просто объединяет в одно

Tags: python, множества

надо чтоб сначала одно заданное множество выводилось, а потом другое. но все элементы просто объединяет в одно. Чтобы потом выполнить над ними операции

```
a = []
s = []
print('Количество множеств')
l = int(input())
for i in range(l):
    print('Количество элементов в множестве')
    n=int(input())
    print('Введите числа')
    for i in range(n):
        a.append(int(input()))
s = set(a)
print(s)
```

Comment: Не вполне понятно, что не получается. Попробуйте пояснить на примере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно просто собирать список в множество внутри цикла по множествам.

```
s = []
print('Количество множеств')
l = int(input())
for i in range(l):
    print('Количество элементов в множестве')
    n=int(input())
    print('Введите числа')
    a = [] # новый список
    for i in range(n):
        a.append(int(input()))
    s.append(set(a)) # добавляем в результирующий список
print(s)
```

Но ещё правильнее собирать данные сразу в множество, минуя список:

```
    a = set()
    for i in range(n):
        a.add(int(input()))
    s.append(a)
```